# How to dequeue correct custom cell type in tableview:cellForRow:AtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm doing a SearchBar and when you type the word "nike" it has to display custom cells "shop Types" that has that name in their title but also the brand nike if it exists in the brands array.

For the moment I manage to get the correct numbers of rows in table view:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(searchActive) {
        return filtered.count + filteredBrands.count
    }
    return shops.count;
}
```

Also managed to filter brands and shops arrays:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = shopNames.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })

    filteredBrands = brandNames.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })

    if(filtered.count == 0 && filteredBrands.count == 0){
        searchActive = false
    } else {
        searchActive = true
    }

    //user pressed the x button to clean content
    if(searchText == "") {
        searchActive = false
    }

    currentTableView.reloadData()
}
```

But now I'm stuck in `tableView:cellForRow:atIndexPath()` :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if(self.brandNamesCopyCounter > 0){
        brandNamesCopyCounter -= 1
        let cell = currentTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("brandCell") as! HomeSearchBrandCell

        if(searchActive){
            if(filteredBrands.count > indexPath.row){
                cell.title.text = filteredBrands[indexPath.row]
                if(cell.iconFacility != nil){
                    cell.iconFacility.image = UIImage.init(named: "brands.pdf")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print(indexPath.row)
            if(brandsArray.count > indexPath.row){
                cell.title.text = brandsArray[indexPath.row].name_en
            }
            if(cell.iconFacility != nil){
                cell.iconFacility.image = UIImage.init(named: "brands.pdf")
            }
        }
        return cell

    }else{
        let cell = currentTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("homeSearchCell") as! HomeSearchCell



        if(searchActive){
            if(filtered.count > indexPath.row){
                print(indexPath.row)
                cell.title.text = self.filtered[indexPath.row]
                if(cell.iconFacility != nil){
                    cell.iconFacility.image = UIImage.init(named: "shops.pdf")
                }
            }
        } else {
            cell.title.text = shops[indexPath.row].name
            if(cell.iconFacility != nil){
                cell.iconFacility.image = UIImage.init(named: "shops.pdf")
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

I really don't have a clue on how to dequeue the correct cell and I'm having weird errors when reuse cells. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this example can help you

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if(section == 0)
       {
         return filtered.count
       }

      return filteredBrands.count
   }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                   var tableCell2 : UITableViewCell
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        tableCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ShopCell") as! ShopCell
    }else
    {
        tableCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BrandsCell") as! BrandsCell
    }

      return tableCell2
   }
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: can you please explain were the "isDriver" Bool comes from?

Comment: If I understand your question, you need use one cell or another when your are showing search results or not, so my isDriver variable is a bool variable only for this example in your case I think you need use your `searchActive` variable, let me know if I am wrong

Comment: No, it's more simple. I need to show different cell types result. So when I'm in table view, I need to differentiate the cells, because I can't load shops data in a brand cell. I need to differentiate the cell. So I can dequeue it with the correct class

Comment: but you are using Strings? why don´t use a model for brands and another for shops or you can use 2 table sections and use the content of one array in one section and the other array in the other

Comment: how can I use two table sections?

Comment: @user3033437 check my edited answer, i hope this help you

Comment: Yes I managed to solve it. I approved your answer. Thanks a lot for your help